# Number of DNA sequences of length $10$ that contain TAGA as a substring

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

DNA sequences are often encoded with the four symbols [C T A G]

How many DNA sequences of length $10$ contain T A G A as a substring?

I'm confused here as to what do they mean by "substring" and how to approach it.  I approached it by doing $\binom{4}{3}$ since there are $4$ spots and $2$ of the letters are repeated.

Comment: Here is an example of such a sequence: TATAGABTGB

Comment: You could "construct" the sequence (with length 10) by starting with TAGA. Then you have to just add letters to one or both sides of TAGA, until you have 10 symbols.

Comment: does that mean I'll have to do 4^10 ?

Comment: You can choose where TAGA appears in the sequence, then choose the other letters.  However, doing so over counts since TAGA could appear twice in the substring, so you will have to subtract the number of sequences in which TAGA appears twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 10 places to fill and for each place you have 4 objects [C T A G]. Each place can be filled by any of the 4 objects. But 4 of the places will be occupied by TAGA. So, now you have 6 other places to fill. So, there are 4^6 ways to that. But, now you have TAGA as an object that can go on any of the seven places (6 places + 1 place for TAGA). So, total ways is 7*(4^6).

But this number also contains possibilities of more than one TAGA as a substring. So, we need to subtract the number of possibilities for which there is more than one TAGA as a substring.

Out of the 10 places there would be 2 TAGA substrings occupying 8 places. So, effectively there are 4 places to fill. The number of ways that can be done is 4 choose 2 that is 6. And remaining 2 places can be filled in 4^2 ways. So, total ways in which the 10 places contain one TAGA as a substring will be

7*(4^6) - 6*(4^2).

Comment: Be careful.  The substring TAGA can appear twice.  You have over counted those cases.

Comment: I assumed TAGA to be appearing only once.

Comment: Your count includes sequences in which TAGA appears twice.

Comment: Yes. I see now. Thanks for pointing out. Will modify the answer

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I modified the answer, accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: Indeed you have.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how  to typeset mathematics on this site.  Welcome to MathSE.

Comment: Will go through the link. Thank you!